# Python attrs/cattrs serializing a dict using frozen attrs classes as the dict keys

Tags: python, json, python-attrs

I would like to structure and unstructure an `attrs` object, which includes `dict` fields that use simple **frozen** attrs for the dict keys. This works very well for objects created at runtime, but the frozen attribute fails to make un/structuring with cattrs easy.

This is a simple example of the problem:

```
import attr, cattr

# Simple attr that contains only a single primitive data type.
@attr.s(frozen=True)
class AbstractID:
    _id: Optional[int] = attr.ib()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        if self._id is not None:
            return f"A{self._id}"
        else:
            return "—"


@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class Database:
    storage: dict[AbstractID, str] = {}

# Attempt to unstructure using cattrs
db = Database()
db.storage[AbstractID(1)] = "some data"

cattr.unstructure(db)

>>> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Is there some way to serialize the data, without using int or str as the dict keys, outside the import/export process?
I saw that cattrs offers hooks to customize the serialization process, but I can't figure out how to reduce the AbstractID to an int when unstructuring, or how to structure it back into an AbstractID.

Can this be done?

Comment: So what you want is `{'storage': {1: 'some data'}}` as the end result?

Comment: Yes, if there is a way to structure it back into Database.storage{AbstractID(1): "some data"}} afterwards, that would be perfectly suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default approach fails since it's trying to generate:

```py
{"storage": {{"_id": 1}: "some_data"}
```

And Python dicts don't support other dicts as keys.

Since we'll be customizing behavior, we'll use a separate instance of a converter. I'll also be using the new attrs APIs since they're cleaner. Here's what you want to do:

```py
from typing import Optional

from attr import define, frozen, Factory

from cattr import GenConverter


# Simple attr that contains only a single primitive data type.
@frozen
class AbstractID:
    _id: Optional[int]

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        if self._id is not None:
            return f"A{self._id}"
        else:
            return "—"


@define
class Database:
    storage: dict[AbstractID, str] = Factory(dict)


# Attempt to unstructure using cattrs
db = Database()
db.storage[AbstractID(1)] = "some data"

c = GenConverter()
c.register_unstructure_hook(AbstractID, lambda aid: aid._id)
c.register_structure_hook(AbstractID, lambda v, _: AbstractID(v))

print(c.unstructure(db))  # {'storage': {1: 'some data'}}
print(c.structure(c.unstructure(db), Database))  # Database(storage={AbstractID(_id=1): 'some data'})
```

`cattrs` makes easy work of this stuff.

Comment: This is perfect, fantastic solution. Btw, I think I recognize your profile picture, you're a (c)attrs contributor and wrote an article about using attrs instead of pydantic, right? I followed your advice and have had a very pleasant experience. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah, that's me. I'm the author of cattrs ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always use [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) for stuff like this. It allows you to fully customize the process via schemas. It is usually a good idea to keep your serialization/deserialization separate from your business logic anyway. So, for your example it could look something like this:

```
from typing import Any
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, post_dump, pre_load, post_load

class AbstractIdSchema(Schema):
    _id = fields.Integer()

    @pre_load
    def pre_load(self, obj: int, **_: Any) -> dict:
        return {'_id': obj}

    @post_load
    def post_load(self, data: dict, **_: Any) -> AbstractID:
        return AbstractID(id=data['_id'])

    @post_dump
    def post_dump(self, data: dict, **_) -> int:
        return data['_id']

class DatabaseSchema(Schema):
    storage = fields.Dict(
        keys=fields.Nested(AbstractIdSchema()),
        values=fields.String(),
    )

    @post_load
    def post_load(self, data: dict, **_: Any) -> Database:
        return Database(**data)

print(db)
db_schema = DatabaseSchema()
serialized_db = db_schema.dump(db)
print(serialized_db)
deserialized_db = db_schema.load(serialized_db)
print(deserialized_db)

# Prints:
# Database(storage={AbstractID(_id=1): 'some data'})
# {'storage': {1: 'some data'}}
# Database(storage={AbstractID(_id=1): 'some data'})
```

It would look a bit simpler if `_id` was just simply `id` (i.e. init arg same as attribute) - then you could do `AbstractID(**data)` in `post_load`.

And then again, it might be an overkill if your models really are that simple. But if reality is more complex, then it might be the way to go.

Comment: When you say "It is usually a good idea to keep your serialization/deserialization separate from your business logic" does that mean I'd use this *alongside* attrs, and basically use this as a method of dumping/loading the data, as an intermediary, or would this *replace* attrs? I'm a little worried about performance and memory usage, which attrs supposedly excel in.

Comment: Alongside, of course. This in no way replaces attrs - it only deals with serialization

Comment: Oh, I see, so the `db_schema.dump(db)` function takes the attrs object and serializes it (assuming the attr object conforms to the schema), replacing the use of cattrs, but not attrs. A solution using cattrs would've been ideal, but this will work just as well, if not better, since it seems pretty easy to implement converters that can convert old databases to newer layouts, even with non-trivial changes. Thanks!